# C++ GDI: I am seeking explanation for color matrix such that I can create any color manipulation mask

Tags: c++, gdi+, colormatrix

I am trying to implement an application that can manipulate the background screen color attributes through a transparent window. Basically trying to recreate [Color Oracle](https://colororacle.org/). I am progressing here through C++:GDI+ resources. This GDI has a *[Color Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-using-a-color-matrix-to-transform-a-single-color-use)* concept. I am able to create filters for greyscale(as shown in the example in the last hyperlink), brightness tweaking, saturation tweaking; However, as advanced use cases such as color blindness filter, blue light filter, contrast tweaks - I am using the hit-n-trial approach, It will be much efficient if anyone can take me in the right direction to learn fundamentals of this color matrix.

Example Matrix is shown below which boosts saturation by a small factor while restricting brightness component.

```
MAGCOLOREFFECT magEffectSaturationBoost =
    { { // MagEffectBright
        {  1.02f,   0.0f,   0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f },
        {   0.0f,  1.02f,   0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f },
        {   0.0f,   0.0f,  1.02f,  0.0f,  1.0f },
        {   0.0f,   0.0f,   0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f },
        {  -0.1f,  -0.1f,  -0.1f,  0.0f,  0.0f }
      }
    }
    // Using the Matrix
    ret = MagSetColorEffect(hwndMag, &magEffectSaturationBoost);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It will be much efficient if anyone can take me in the right direction to learn fundamentals of this color matrix.

Each color vector is multipled by 5x5 matrix, to make it possible color vector is 5 elements long - the fifth element is a dummy one, this allows to perform additional operations on colors (rotation, scaling, ...).

In your example each color component is multiplied by 1.02f making color brighter, after multiplication - from each color component 0.1 value is subtracted.

You can find full explanation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-using-a-color-matrix-to-transform-a-single-color-use

and:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-coordinate-systems-and-transformations-about

Few more links:

https://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide/

https://www.integral-domain.org/lwilliams/math150/labs/matrixcolorfilter.php

Comment: Thank you @marcinj, I have already gone through the links you provided! There, I didn't find the detailed solution, to explore further - I want to know how we can use other than *diagonal elements* to get more masks, role of negative sign if any. 
Thanks for the help, again :)

Comment: @SourabhDesai The key is to understand that this transformation works the same as in case of vector transformations for 3D points, but it has different meanings in case of colors. This is a broad topic so I doubt you will get a long and through guide as SO is more about solving specific problems. I have added two additional links for you, which might help you in understanding different transformations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the tool I was looking for, now I can explore this matrix with ease.